# Existence of two stochastic processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am wondering if I can show that

> For given $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ there are two stochastic processes $S_t$ and $B_t$ such that $S_t$ and $B_t$ are two one dimensional Brownian motions starting at $x$ and $y$ respectively and $P\{S_t = B_t\}=1$ for $t>>0$.

I thank in advance for any help!

Comment: This is called coalescent brownian motion. Set $T=\inf{t:S_t=B_t}$ and set $W_t = 1_{t\leq T}S+1_{t>T}B_t$.

Comment: @RaphaelB4 Thank you!  I think I got the idea but, with the notation given by you, I cannot see how it is possible to show $P\{S_t=B_t\}=1$. Could I have more hint?

Comment: @RaphaelB4  If I understand correctly, the $W_t$ in your explanation is the Brownian motion starting from $x$ and coincide with $B_t^y$ for $t >T$. Now, I see why they are equal for large enough $t$. But I am still thinking why then $W_t$ is Brownian motion.

Comment: @RaphaelB4 Actually, come to think of it, $T$ does not need to be finite which means it cannot solve my problem.

Comment: $T<\infty$ almost surely but it is not bounded. If you want the equallity for a fixed $t$ it is not possible as the gaussian law $\mathcal{N}(x,t)$ and $\mathcal{N}(y,t)$ are different.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @RaphaelB4, I could figure out the proof even for general $d-$dimensional case. Here is my proof.

Let $B_t^x$ and $B_t^y$ be two independent $1-$dimensional Brownian motions with initial points $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$ respectively. Now, let
\begin{align*}
\tau=\inf\{t\geq 0 : B_t^x=B_t^y\}
 \end{align*}

then note that $\tau<\infty$ a.s. because $1D$ Brownian motion is recurrent. Now, consider $W_t^y=B_t^y\chi_{[0,\tau ]}+B_t^x\chi_{(\tau,\infty)}$ then $W_t^y$ is a $1-$dimensional Brownian motion with initial point $y$ and with $P\{B_t^x=W_t^y 
\text{ for all $t>\tau$} \}=1.$

Now, we want to construct $d-$dimensional Brownian motion for arbitrary $d\in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^d$ be given. Then, by the result above, for each $i\in \{1,\dots, d\}$, if $x_i$ and $y_i$ are $i$th entries of vectors $x$ and $y$, there exist two $1-$dimensional Brownian motions $B_t^{x_i}$ and $B_t^{y_i}$ with initial points $x_i$ and $y_i$ respectively such that $P\{B_t^{x_i}=B_t^{y_i} \text{ for all }t\geq\tau_i \}=1$ where $\tau_i=\inf\{t\geq 0 :B_t^{x_i}=B_t^{y_i}\}$.   Now, let $B_t^x$ and $B_t^y$ be $\mathbb{R}^d$ valued function such that
\begin{align*}
B_t^x=\begin{bmatrix}
B_t^{x_1}\\
\vdots\\
B_t^{x_d}
\end{bmatrix}\hspace{4cm}
B_t^y=\begin{bmatrix}
B_t^{y_1}\\
\vdots\\
B_t^{y_d}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Now, let $T=\max_{ i} \tau_i$. Noting that $P\{\tau_i<\infty\}=1$ we know that
\begin{align*}
P\{T<\infty \}=P\left( \bigcap_i \{\tau_i<\infty\} \right)=1.
\end{align*}
(https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/100576)

Then $B_t^x$ and $B_t^y$ are two $d-$dimensional Brownian motions such that $P\{B_t^x=B_t^y \text{  for all }t>T\}=1$.

Comment: @PierrePC Thanks for pointing that out. You are absolutely right. Maybe I need to make the last $T$ specific.

Comment: @PierrePC The reason why they are equal in one dimensional case is because brownian motion is recurrent in one dimensional case. In the case of multidimension, the equality get changed to less than equal to.

Comment: @PierrePC Ah.... Yeah... Come to think of it.... you are right.

Comment: In $d > 1$ case, if you need a minimal coupling time $T$, then look up "mirror coupling" of Brownian motions.